# Duplicate caused by Migration

Tags: discussion

A question was asked both here and at SO.  The one at SO got a response, then got migrated here.  Now there are two duplicates here, with answers on both of them.  I deleted my answer from one of them, leaving it with both answers.  The name of both questions is this:

Completion of ERD, uncertainties about generalization/specialization and primary keys

Can one of them simply be deleted (probably the one with no answers).

Comment: You can flag one of the two (the one with no answer) for moderator attention, adding a link to the other one. I've already voted to be closed as duplicate, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the heads up; these questions have been merged.

However, in the future, please just flag the question; this is a relatively common occurrence, and we shouldn't have a meta discussion every time it happens.

What you've done in this case is actually created two duplicate answers, but you deleted one with comments:

> [image]

Comment: I agree that a meta discussion shouldn't be necessary on each occurrence.  I didn't see the handle on voting to close on the one that should be closed, possibly because it was already locked.

Comment: @WalterMitty You don't have enough rep (3000) in dba.se to vote for closing yet.

Comment: @WalterMitty close votes require a certain rep as ypercube has pointed out, but flagging should always be an option.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'll go ahead and learn how that is done.  (These days, with so much to learn, I tend to learn new things only on a need-to-know basis).